# What does the Chrome output mean?

Tags: razor, google-chrome-devtools

I get output showing up on the Chrome debug console like
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at (program) (localhost/Members/Payments/PaymentSuccess?473876=:4:1)
I have no idea where to start to look and I was wondering if anyone know what '473876=:4:1' means? Or if that part of the output is useful.